# Placing and resizing JPanel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to have a `JFrame` with a `JPanel` that looks like this.

[image: Sample layout]

The 2 panels on the left side 60% width and 50% height each then the panel on the right side 40% width and 100% height
How can I achieve this?

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
   public class INV{

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JPanel Outer_panel1;
private JPanel Outer_panel2;
private JPanel Panel1;
private JPanel Panel2;
private JPanel Panel3;
private JPanel Panel4;
private JButton b1;
private JButton b2;
private JButton b3;
private JComboBox List;
private JComboBox List2;
private JTextField Item_name;
private JTextField Dec_qty;
private JTextField Inc_qty;
private static String[] Items = {"wood","steel"};
private JTable Table;
private JScrollPane Scroll;
static double xsize;
static double ysize;

    public INV(){
        gui();
    }

    public void gui(){
        mainFrame = new JFrame("sample");
        GridBagConstraints Con = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Left Panel
        Dec_qty=new JTextField(3); 
        Inc_qty=new JTextField(3); 
        List = new JComboBox(Items);
        List2 = new JComboBox(Items);
        b1 = new JButton("OK");
        b2 = new JButton("OK");


        Outer_panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Outer_panel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        Panel1 = new JPanel();
        Panel1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        Panel2 = new JPanel();
        Panel2.setBackground(Color.red);



        Outer_panel1.add(b1);
        Outer_panel1.add(b2);

        Panel1.add(List);
        Panel2.add(List2);
        Panel1.add(Inc_qty);
        Panel2.add(Dec_qty);
        Panel1.add(b1);
        Panel2.add(b2);

        Con.gridx = 0;
        Con.gridy = 0;
        Con.ipady = 300;
        Con.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        Outer_panel1.add(Panel1,Con);
        Con.gridx = 0;
        Con.gridy = 1;
        Con.ipady = 0;
        Con.weighty = 1.0;
        Outer_panel1.add(Panel2,Con);


        mainFrame.add(Outer_panel1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);


        //right panel
        Outer_panel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Outer_panel2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        Panel3 = new JPanel();
        Panel3.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        Panel4 = new JPanel();
        Panel4.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        //Panel3
        Item_name =new JTextField(20); 
        b3 = new JButton("Search");

        //Panel4 and Table
        String[] columnNames = {"column1","column2"};
        Object[][] data = {{"sample1","sample2"},
                            {"sample3","sample4"}};

        Table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        Table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        Table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        Scroll = new JScrollPane(Table);

        Panel3.add(Item_name);
        Panel3.add(b3);
        Panel4.add(Scroll);

        Con.gridx = 0;
        Con.gridy = 0;
        Con.ipady = 0;
        Con.weighty = 0;
        Outer_panel2.add(Panel3, Con);
        Con.gridx = 0;
        Con.gridy = 1;
        Con.ipady = 0;  
        Con.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        Con.weighty = 1.0;

        Outer_panel2.add(Panel4, Con);
        mainFrame.add(Outer_panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setSize(900, 500);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }


public static void main(String[] args){
    new INV();
}
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: *"I can't resize and place the panel to the size that I want."*  As an aside, the size of a `JPanel` is typically best set according to the size of whatever it contains.  Do any of these panels have content (controls, labels etc.) inside them?

Comment: The yellow and black panel has drop down list, textfield and a submit button while the red panel has a textfield, a button beside it and a table with 2 columns under the textfield

Comment: which of JPanels can/can't be resizable with contianer, all, two, one .... ???

Comment: Again, SSCCE (include the content of the panels) & How is the extra space assigned?  From your description it seems it would be best given to the black area that does not contain any components.  ..but I am not about to show how to do it without an SSCCE and the other information..

Comment: @AndrewThompson is this enough info?

Comment: I don't see those components you mentioned.  Components that I would use to give a preferred size to the panels.  Really, it should not be so hard to get basic information..

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is the code that I got when I start from scratch again....  I cant put the right size that I want on the left and right panels.. the two panels on the left side should be 60% width and 50% height of the window each and the right side 40% width and 80% height on the table and 40% width and 20% height of the window

Comment: There are too many things wrong with your code to enumerate.  Java is not JavaScript.  Designing a GUI is not the same as putting a web page together.  You must learn how to put together a Swing GUI, piece by small piece.  You will code many classes and many more methods.  Don't make one monolithic JavaScript Java module.  No one, including you, will understand it.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never control the size manually. What if the user wants to resize?? You wilk have to do useless computations while java will happily do it for you using layout manager.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind and will learn from that link you just gave

Comment: @John And don't forget that you can put Layouts inside other layouts in order to obtain the design you want. For example: A Panel (BorderLayout) inside another JPanel (CardLayout), etc.

Comment: ohh ok.. but how can I set the size of the layout? for example the panel on the east will occupy 60% of the window while the west panel will occupy 40% of the window... cause when I did this the size of the panel inside the panel is dependent on the content of the panel inside the panel

Comment: @John Why would you need to do so? With the layout Managers, you can use the knowledge of "preferedSize" and let the managers handle resizing correctly. The only place where you really need to set a size in my opinion would be for the main Frame and for a JSplitPane (And I don't mean the size of the component but the position of the splitter)

Comment: I tried the layout managers and I got stucked on this one 
http://s909.photobucket.com/user/crizied/media/sample.png.html?sort=3&o=0
I was hoping to get the panels on the left to be equal size but it turns out that you need to fullscreen the window so that you can see the rest of the panel at the bottom left

here is the code that I used on that part
   Con.gridx = 0;
   Con.gridy = 0;
   Con.ipady = 300;
   Con.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
   Outer_panel1.add(Panel1,Con);
   Con.gridx = 0;
   Con.gridy = 1;
   Con.ipady = 0;
   Con.weighty = 1.0;
   Outer_panel1.add(Panel2,Con);

Comment: @John I think you are using the GridBagConstraints wrongly. Check this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Ive just updated my codes that I posted.. I still dont get how will I get the result that I want. I'm still stucked on this one -_- can you please help me with my codes?

Answer (score -1):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setSize(600, 400);

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 200);
panel1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
panel1.setLayout(null);

JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setBounds(400, 0, 200, 400);
panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
panel2.setLayout(null);

JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
panel3.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
panel3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
panel3.setLayout(null);

panel3.add(panel1);
panel3.add(panel2);
frame.add(panel3);

//YOU CAN USE  LAYOUT = NULL TO MANUALLY POSITION YOUR PANELS
//IT IS BEST TO USE LAYOUT MANAGERS, BUT SETTING THE POSITIONS MANUALLY IS THE EASIEST
//SPECIALLY IF YOU WILL JUST .setResizable(false)
```

Comment: thank you for the help but when i resize it the size of the panel is fixed... but I'll try to find a way to resize the panels when the user resize the frame

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  -1.  Please learn why before giving any further advice on GUIs.  We spend too much time correcting the mistakes made using that advice, as it is.